# Is it possible to achieve temeplatization in C as it is possible in C++

Tags: c++, c

I want to write a function in C that will accept any type of data types like int, char, float, or any other data type and do some operation on them. As this is possible in C++, is it possible in C?

Answer (score 9):

It wouldn't be pretty. Take a look at [this page](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Faking_Templates_In_C.shtml) for an example. Lots of macro usage.

Comment: You say that as if C++ templates were "pretty". ;-)

Comment: @Paul R, They're...prettier. ;)

Comment: I'm going to add your link to my answer. It's another excellent example in addition to the really small one I gave.

Comment: @Paul R "Pretty" in the sense that they're type-safe and actually parsed as a language construct, rather than being a text substitution hack.

Answer (score 1):

About the only thing you can do in C is macros, the poor cousins of templates. For example:

```
#define max(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (b) : (a))
```

Note that this has a huge problem... the macro arguments are evaluated more than once. For example:

```
max(i+=1, i);
```

expands to:

```
((i+=1) < (i) ? (i+=1) : (i));
```

And the result of that expression could be all kinds of interesting things on various compilers.

So, macros are really a poor substitute for templates. You can make 'functions' that are type agnostic with them. But they come with a number of hurdles and pitfalls that make them practically useless for anything really significant. They are also rather 'hairy' and make your code a lot harder to understand than templates do.

The `max` example I just gave may not seem that hairy (though the doubled evaluation of arguments is certainly a surprising and difficult to deal with thing), but [here is an example of declaring something like a templated vector type with macros, and it is obviously hairy](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Faking_Templates_In_C.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

You can create and accept a `union`, or you can take a pointer to the data using the generic `void*`. C doesn't, however, support templating as in C++.

Comment: I have a doubt, to use the value inside the called function we have to know the data type of the value which is passed from the calling function, as we can't use the void pointer without typecasting it into proper data type. So this is not complete templating. Pardon me if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved by using macros. See
http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Faking_Templates_In_C.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can arrange a cheat using `...` e.g. with `varargs` function

Answer (score 0):

I guess it must be a void pointer

```
  void *p;
```

Just typecast and use it. what you have asked is the limitation of c thats why it is introduced in c++

After reading your comment i guess you need an argument to send the datatype of variable

```
 func( void *p, int ) \\ second argument must be a datatype use sizeof to find the datatype
```

Comment: Thank you... Yes , using one data type field we can achieve somewhat templatization in C.

Comment: But i guess it must be pretty long code writing the if conditions for it and typecasting it :)

Comment: @niko: You could try to implement things in terms of functions that take void pointers and sizes, like `memcpy` etc. I suspect that's how functions like `qsort` can be generic.